# how to access table from schema 1 to schema 2?

Tags: sql, oracle

how to access table from schema 1 to schema 2 ?

Comment: select * from schema1.tablea  join schema2.tableb

Comment: Have you tried reading [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/tablecls.htm#GUID-72E247B5-F39A-47F1-9445-72D9221F57E3)?

Answer (score 1):

You simply access table from another schema by adding schema name in query.

```
select * from schema1.table;
```

But that's not enough. You can still get error that table not exist because user that is trying to access table need to have grant to select it. So on `schema1` or `sys` you need to execute:

```
grant select on schema1.table to schema2;
```